# Use of vtkCylindricalTransform with paraview

Tags: visualization, vtk, paraview

My code outputs a scalar and vector attributes in cylindrical coordinates and outputs them in an HDF5 file. There is a corresponding XDMF file that defines the Geometry like this:

```
<Geometry GeometryType="VXVYVZ">
    <DataItem Name="r" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" ...>
        my_file.hdf5:/coordinates/r
    </DataItem>
    <DataItem Name="theta" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" ...>
        my_file.hdf5:/coordinates/theta
    </DataItem>
    <DataItem Name="z" Dimensions="40" NumberType="Float" ...>
        my_file.hdf5:/coordinates/z
    </DataItem>
</Geometry>
```

Is it possible, inside Paraview, to use `vtkCylindricalTransform`, or any other means, to transform the StructuredMesh in cylindrical coordinates to an UnstructuredMesh in Cartesian coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in using the `Clean to Grid` filter, which converts the structured grid to an unstructured one. Then, in the `Calculator` filter, it is possible to tick the `Coordinate Results` box and perform the transform there, i.e.:

```
coordsX*cos(coordsY)*iHat+coordsX*sin(coordsY)*jHat+coordsZ*kHat
```

which then allows to visualize the data in Cartesian coordinates.